# Phone and PC microphones receive different audio frequency

Tags: android, audio, shazam

I'm making a Shazam program, and when using my phone to receive sound, the frequencies I'm picking up are different from the ones I get from my computer.
Why does it happen? How can it be solved? (I'm using the same method to extract the frequencies from both the phone and the PC).

Comment: Different mic/hardware, how different are they?

Comment: the difference is 11 hz

Comment: Sounds like a sound engineering question! The microphone, preamp, A/D converter, mic position etc, will all make a difference. Probably nothing to do with your software, so unlikely a programming question.

Comment: 11 Hz at what expected frequency? 11Hz from 20Hz is a lot more than 11Hz in 20kHz.